# VS Application Insights for a Web App deployed to multiple environments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, configuration, azure-application-insights

I'm in the process of trialling MS Application Insgihts on a Web Application deployed to Azure.

One thing that doesn't seem to be available out of the box is segregation of stats/anayltics by deployment environment.

Just wondering has anyone done this already and how the went about achieving it?

Here's what I was thinking.

- Create 4 seperate "Applications" within AI (each with their own App Name & Component Id)
- Add a single ApplicationInsights.config to the Web Application Project
- Manually Add App.Config Transforms to the application to replace the ComponentName & ComponentId at build time based on the Configuratoin (QA, UAT or Prod)
- Add Conditional Compilation Symbols to the Web Application Build Configurations (QA, UAT, PROD)
- Add "#if QA" pre-processor directives to the razor _layout view to swap in the correct ComponentId into the javascript snippet at build time.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what we did.

- Create 4 AI applications
- In our ApplicationInsights.config we set it to our development componentId.
- For Test, Stage, and Prod we use a build script that replaces the componentId and componentName based on which environment we are in.
- In layout javascript get the appId:

  ```
  appInsights.start("@ServerAnalytics.ApplicationInsightsId");
  ```

Answer (score -1):

I found this on msdn blogs from January 7, 2015 [Application Insights support for Multiple Environments, Stamps and App Versions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/01/07/application-insights-support-for-multiple-environments-stamps-and-app-versions/).

Basically, you can remove the instrumentation key from `ApplicationInsights.config` and put it in `Web.config` as an appSetting and then set it at startup.

This means that you can keep the configuration for each environment directly in azure.

My steps:

1. Delete `<InstrumentationKey>` from `ApplicationInsights.config`
2. Add the setting in Web.config

   `<add key="appInsightsInstrumentationKey" value="id_from hre"/>`
3. Add settings in http://portal.azure.com for Dev, Sta, etc
4. On startup:

   `var aiInstrumentationKey = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appInsightsInstrumentationKey"];
   if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(aiInstrumentationKey))
   {
       throw new ApplicationException("appInsightsInstrumentationKey missing in web.config");
   }
   Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = aiInstrumentationKey;`